ClosedXML exporta Excel con error No property or field '...' exists in type '<CastIterator>d__97`1' desde columna 33
Tengo el siguiente template xlsx:



Column1Lbl
Column2Lbl
...
Column30Lbl
Column31Lbl
Column32Lbl
Column33Lbl




{{item.Column1}}
{{item.Column2}}
...
{{item.Column30}}
{{item.Column31}}
{{item.Column32}}
{{item.Column33}}




...







A la hora de exportar pasa esto:



Título 1
Título 2
...
Título 30
Título 31
Título 32
Título 33




Dato 1 1
Dato 2 1
...
Dato 30 1
Dato 31 1
No property or field 'column32' exists in type 'd__97`1'
No property or field 'column33' exists in type 'd__97`1'


Dato 1 2
Dato 2 2
...
Dato 30 2
Dato 31 2




Dato 1 3
Dato 2 3
...
Dato 30 3
Dato 31 3






...







Como dato curioso puedo colocar la columna 30 en el lugar de la 32 y la 32 en el lugar de la 30 (copiando y pegando), y pasa esto:



Título 1
Título 2
...
Título 30
Título 31
Título 32
Título 33




Dato 1 1
Dato 2 1
...
Dato 32 1
Dato 20 1
No property or field 'column30' exists in type 'd__97`1'
No property or field 'column33' exists in type 'd__97`1'


Dato 1 2
Dato 2 2
...
Dato 32 2
Dato 20 2




Dato 1 3
Dato 2 3
...
Dato 32 3
Dato 20 3






...







Notar también que los títulos se procesaron bien.
En el código fuente tengo esto:
        var template = new XLTemplate(PropertiesFile.GetRequiredProperty(PropertiesFile.TEMPLATE_PATH));

        var dataShipments = new DataTable();
        dataShipments.Columns.Add("Column1", typeof(string));
        dataShipments.Columns.Add("Column2", typeof(string));
        ...
        dataShipments.Columns.Add("Column30", typeof(string));
        dataShipments.Columns.Add("Column31", typeof(string));
        dataShipments.Columns.Add("Column32", typeof(string));
        dataShipments.Columns.Add("Column33", typeof(string));


        IQueryable<IGrouping<string, DataItems>> groupItemsByColumn2 = dataItems.GroupBy(item => item.column2);

        foreach (IGrouping<string, DataItems> groupedItemByColumn2 in groupItemsByColumn2)
        {
            IList<DataItems> items = groupedItemByColumn2.ToList();
            foreach (DataItems item in items)
            {
                //Aquíe es donde se asignan los valores:
                DataRow newRow = dataShipments.NewRow();
                newRow["Column1"] = item.Column1 ?? string.Empty;
                newRow["Column2"] = item.Column2 ?? string.Empty;
                ...
                newRow["Column30"] = item.Column30 ?? string.Empty;
                newRow["Column31"] = item.Column31 ?? string.Empty;
                newRow["Column32"] = item.Column32 ?? string.Empty;
                newRow["Column33"] = item.Column33 ?? string.Empty;
                dataShipments.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
        }

        template.AddVariable("item",dataShipments);

        //Lo siguiente parece que funciona bien debido a que se aplican todos los títulos:
        template.AddVariable("Column1Lbl", "Títlo 1");
        template.AddVariable("Column2Lbl", "Títlo 2");
        ...
        template.AddVariable("Column30Lbl", "Títlo 30");
        template.AddVariable("Column31Lbl", "Títlo 31");
        template.AddVariable("Column32Lbl", "Títlo 32");
        template.AddVariable("Column33Lbl", "Títlo 33");

        template.Generate();

